# Will Windows 11 accept 6 touchmonitors and work out of the box?

Tags: windows, touchscreen

Need to build a Windows 11 machine which can run 6 monitors with touch simultaneously. All monitors will run in "extended desktop" mode.

Thinking of building a computer with 2 graphic cards (RTX 3050) which each can drive 3 monitors via DisplayPort.

Will connecting 6 touchscreens to this computer work as intended, or are there any limitations to such setups?

One mouse and one keyboard will also be added, which ends up connecting in total 8 USB ports with Windows HID drivers (Human Interface Device).

Monitors would be of type *Philips 222B1TC/00* or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be a problem with running six monitors on any modernish version of Windows.  Looking around, I see mention of a limit of 10 monitors for the built-in Display Properties control panel, but that can be worked around with software that is designed to manage large numbers of displays.

Here's an excerpt from https://techbullish.com/how-many-monitors-can-windows-10-support/

> Windows 10 has multiple features that enable it to support a maximum of ten monitors. However, this limit is set by the Display Properties Applet found in the Control Panel. You can use a custom display properties applet to configure more than ten monitors.

Comment: Finally tested, and works.